# Transparent bitmaps as resources?

Tags: delphi, bitmap, resources, delphi-2009

I want to compile a resource file with `brcc32` that has a 32bit Bitmap and I receive an error message: `Error: Invalid bitmap format`. If I save the bitmap in 24bit format, it is copiled successfully, but I lose transparency... It is really not possible to have transparent bitmap as resources or I miss something ?

Comment: Use Microsoft tools, rc in this case

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did that and it works... But when I try to load it in mai application it says that it doesn't exists. I opened it with an resource editor, and that bitmap was created as an RCDATA instead of BITMAP.

Comment: No such problem here. I guess you made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

brcc32 does not support creating 32bit `BITMAP` resources. So either

- use a different resource compiler/editor that supports 32bit bitmaps.
- create the bitmap resource as an `RCDATA` resource instead of a `BITMAP` resource.

Comment: Ok, but if I create the bitmap as an `RCDATA`, I can't load it in a TBitmap with `LoadFromResourceName` method...

Comment: @MarusNebunu `RCDATA` is just an arbitrary type, which can be loaded into a stream, and then further loaded into the bitmap from there.

Comment: @MarusNebunu true, but you can use  a `TResourceStream` with `TBitmap.LoadFromStream()` instead